# Locally constant integer sheaf over riemann surface higher cohomology vanishes?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

The reason I am asking this question is the following. Consider $D$ any divisor over Riemann surface $X$. Denote any $U\subset X$ biholomorphic to an open disk of $C$. Denote $O_D=\{f\in M(U)|(f)+D\geq 0\}$ where $(f)$ is the divisor of $f$ and $M(X)$ is meromorphic functions over $U$.

In Forster Lectures on Riemann Surfaces Exercise 16.3, it asks to show that $H^1(U,O_D)=0$ for any $D$ divisor which in turn implies open disk covering $X$ will form Leray covering against $O_D$ sheaf.

Now consider the sheaf exact sequence $0\to Z\to O\xrightarrow{exp}O^\star\to 0$ where $O^\star$ is the sheaf non-vanishing holomorphic functions. Take cohomology against $U$. One obtains $0\to Z\to O(U)\to O^\star(U)\to H^1(U,Z)\to H^1(U,O)\to H^1(U,O^\star)\to H^2(U,Z)\to\dots$

Now $H^1(U,O)=0$ by Dolbeault Lemma/Thm and $H^1(U,Z)=0$ by $H^1(U,C)=0$.(Actually, I think $H^1$ for any simply connected manifold vanishes for $Z,C$ sheafs as the proof involves only partition of unity, basic arithmetic and exponentiation operations.) I want to see whether $H^1(U,O^\star)$ vanishing.(i.e. I am asking whether open disks form Leray covering for $O^\star$.)

$\textbf{Q:}$ Does $H^2(U,Z)=0$ for $U$ disk where $Z$ is locally constant integer sheaf? I am asking whether $U$ is a Leray covering of $O^\star$.

$\textbf{Q':}$ Is there a characterization for what kind of sheaf over disk has trivial cohomology? Is this a topological characterization? I guess it is not as for smooth function sheaf, I need to assume smooth structure to deduce partition of unity which will show triviality of $H^1$ for sheaf of smooth functions.

Comment: If $X$ is any simplicial complex then sheaf cohomology with constant coefficients is isomorphic to simplicial (or singular) cohomology (with the same coefficients). Hence, it vanishes above the dimension of the complex.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Then it will indeed be the case.

Comment: In topology, cohomology with coefficients in a constant sheaf is known as Chech cohomology. See for instance, Eilenberg and Steenrod "Algebraic Topology" for a proof of the isomorphism theorem I mentioned as well as for the proof that contractible spaces are acyclic (have zero reduced cohomology).

Comment: @MoisheCohen Where do I find cech cohomology in algebraic topology reference, it is not in standard textbook? I have seen cech cohomology in the context of algebraic geometry for sheaf cohomology computation only.

Comment: See Eilenberg and Steenrod. Or Bredon's book "Sheaf Theory", although the latter will cover much more than you need. Bredon covers sheaf cohomology from the general topology perspective.

Answer (score 1):

While everything Moishe said in the comments is true, it's worth noting that you are taking cohomology of a sheaf over a contractible space, since you're interested here only in $H^i(U, \mathbb{Z})$, where $U$ is biholomorphic to a disk. Since $U$ is contractible, it has the cohomology of a point, and so all cohomologies vanish above degree $0$.